# Can you prevent being automatically added to gchat groups upon being invited?

Tags: google-hangouts

I have been invited to a group chat that I don't want to be in. I left the group and then was re-invited. The invitations automatically bring me into the group, complete with pop-up notifications and all.

I don't want to block the people inviting me to the group since they are acquaintances and friends that I routinely gchat with individually, but I would prefer to have a say in whether or not I join the group. Is there a way to prevent auto-joining all groups I'm invited to?

I don't want to be forcefully pulled into a group chat and have the notifications popping up for a conversation I don't even have any interest in.

Answer (score 2):

I know that this question is old, but for people who come here searching for answers, you need to:

> For in Browser:

1) Open Hangouts and navigate to settings by clicking the down arrow next to your name

2) Click on "Customize invite settings"

3) Select Customized, *and choose who needs an invite and who doesn’t*.

> For in app

1) Open The hangouts App

2) Click on the 'Menu' button and navigate to settings

3) choose your email

4) Click on Customize invitations *and choose who needs an invite and who doesn’t*.

From: https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/hangouts/uH_8zIv8rBs/3QvjLVVHCAAJ

Comment: Thanks for the edit, @jonsca. I totally forgot to source it!

Comment: No problem.  I appreciate very much that you complied.

Comment: Old but still relevant and I still face this issue. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, @leigero!